# Why is it that when I yawn, I hardly hear anything

Tags: hearing, yawning-yawn

I've confirmed this a lot of people and I've noticed I ain't the only one with this experience. When I yawn, it's hard for me to hear what anyone is saying.

So my question is - **Is this normal or there's something wrong somewhere**